# Not able to find the Group while parsing FIX message using QuikFix

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

We are receiving FIX message from a source database and have to parse and store in our System. These are from ICE exchange (WebICE) and we are using QuickFix and FIX42.xml data dictionary to parse the messages.

We are able to parse Execution Reports and UDS (User defined Strategies) successfully but its failing for Security Definition when trying to parse the repeating groups.

Below is a sample code with message.

```
val testMessage = "8=FIX.4.2^A9=97129^A35=d^A49=ICE^A34=21^A52=20200904-11:00:16.742^A56=8428^A57=123abc^A322=1^A323=4^A320=XX_Security_Request 0^A9064=0^A393=19275^A82=193^A67=1^A711=3^A311=2322323^A309=MSS SDU0320.U0320^A308=IFED^A305=8^A9013=0.001^A9133=2.500^A9134=2.500^A9040=0.001^A9041=2500^A307=XYXYXYXYXYX^A763=0^A1039=C^A9014=2500.0^A9017=57500.0^A326=17^A998=TEST TEST^A318=USD^A9083=3^A9084=0^A9085=daily^A9061=467^A9062=TEST TEST Futures^A9063=Product Description^A9032=2.500^A9030=1^A9132=2.500^A9091=Test Malin^A9092=1^A9093=0^A9095=Energy^A9215=0^A9217=0^A9205=0^A436=1.0^A9216=0^A463=FXXXXX^A542=20200904^A9100=USD^A9101=USD / TEST TEST^A9022=1^A9024=1.0^A9049=1^A9203=1^A9025=Y^A916=20200903^A917=20200903^A9201=69360^A9200=4^A9202=03 Sep 20^A9300=656^A9301=TEST Gas Transmission - Malin^A9302=PGT-Malin^A9303=MSS^A9034=1^A9070=16^A9071=0^A9072=K^A9073=25.0^A9071=1^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A311=624232323233062^A309=PES SDU0320.U0320^A308=IFED^A305=8^A9013=0.001^A9133=2.500^A9134=2.500^A9040=0.001^A9041=2500^A307=Test Desc Futures - Permian (EP) - 03 Sep 20^A763=0^A1039=C^A9014=2500.0^A9017=57500.0^A326=17^A998=TEST TEST^A318=USD^A9083=3^A9084=0^A9085=daily^A9061=476^A9062=TEST TEST Futures^A9063=Product Description ^A9032=2.500^A9030=1^A9132=2.500^A9091=Test EPPermian^A9092=1^A9093=0^A9095=Energy^A9215=0^A9217=0^A9205=0^A436=1.0^A9216=0^A463=FXXXXX^A542=20200904^A9100=USD^A9101=USD / TEST TEST^A9022=1^A9024=1.0^A9049=1^A9203=1^A9025=Y^A916=20200903^A917=20200903^A9201=69360^A9200=4^A9202=03 Sep 20^A9300=665^A9301=El Paso - Permian Basin^A9302=Permian (EP)^A9303=PES^A9034=1^A9070=16^A9071=0^A9072=K^A9073=25.0^A9071=1^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A311=23232323^A309=SCS SDU0320.U0320^A308=IFED^A305=8^A9013=0.001^A9133=2.500^A9134=2.500^A9040=0.001^A9041=2500^A307=Test Desc Futures - Socal-TEST - 03 Sep 20^A763=0^A1039=C^A9014=2500.0^A9017=57500.0^A326=17^A998=TEST TEST^A318=USD^A9083=3^A9084=0^A9085=daily^A9061=1462^A9062=TEST TEST Futures^A9063=Product Description ^A9032=2.500^A9030=1^A9132=2.500^A9091=Test Socal Cty^A9092=1^A9093=0^A9095=Energy^A9215=0^A9217=0^A9205=0^A436=1.0^A9216=0^A463=FXXXXX^A542=20200904^A9100=USD^A9101=USD / TEST TEST^A9022=1^A9024=1.0^A9049=1^A9203=1^A9025=Y^A916=20200903^A917=20200903^A9201=69360^A9200=4^A9202=03 Sep 20^A9300=1277^A9301=Socal - TEST^A9302=Socal-TEST^A9303=SCS^A9034=1^A9070=16^A9071=0^A9072=K^A9073=25.0^A9071=1^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=K^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=V^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=S^A9073=1.0^A9071=0^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=1^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=2^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A9071=3^A9072=E^A9073=1.0^A10=210^A"

  val dd: DataDictionary = new DataDictionary("FIX42.xml")
  val message: Message = new quickfix.Message(testMessage,dd)
  val noOfunderlyings= message.getInt(711)
  println("Underlyings "+noOfunderlyings)

  for(i <- 1 to noOfunderlyings ) {
    val FixGroup: Group = message.getGroup(i, 711)
    println("UnderlyingSecurityID : " + FixGroup.getString(309))
  }
```

Failing at line : **val FixGroup: Group = message.getGroup(i, 711)**

With below error message

```
Exception in thread "main" quickfix.FieldNotFound: 711, index=1
    at quickfix.FieldMap.getGroup(FieldMap.java:644)
```

We have checked the data dictionary and the repeating groups are present there. Also same data dictionary has been used at source end in FIX client engine to receive messages from exchange.

Data dictionary : [Data Dictionary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zUOPHMTc_6xxkcptVfUHCE9iEt1TFpLY/view?usp=sharing)

This has became a bottleneck for us at the moment. Requesting help from all fellow SO users.

Segment of DD
9064 tag -> ExchangeSilo  (Int)

711 tag -> NoUnderlyings   (NumInGroup)

```
 <message name='SecurityDefinition' msgtype='d' msgcat='app'>
            <field name='SecurityResponseID' required='Y' />
            <field name='SecurityResponseType' required='N' />
            <field name='SecurityReqID' required='Y' />
            <field name='SecurityID' required='N' />
            <field name='ExchangeSilo'  required='N' />
            <field name='TotalNumSecurities' required='Y' />
            <field name='Symbol' required='N' />
            <field name='NoRpts' required='N' />
            <field name='ListSeqNo' required='N' />
            <!-- USEFUL FOR THE NEW SECURITY DEFINITION RESPONSE-->
            <group name='NoUnderlyings' required='N'>
                <field name='UnderlyingSymbol' required='N' />
                <field name='UnderlyingSecurityID' required='N' />
                <field name='UnderlyingSecurityExchange' required='N' />
                <field name='UnderlyingIDSource' required='N' />
                <field name='IncrementPrice' required='N' />
                <field name='ScreenTickValue' required='N' />
```

Comment: Could you maybe post the `testMessage` with visible delimiters, e.g. pipe symbol `|`? Otherwise it is hard to tell where one tag ends and the other starts. What's the tag after 320? Is it 9064 or only 64? If the first, is it defined in your data dictionary? Maybe it is unknown and that breaks the parser? Could you please print out the message after it has been parsed? My assumption is that the parsing is broken because of the unknown tag and that is why 711 is not found. OTOH, that would probably not correctly print out your underlyings. So you are getting 33 there?

Comment: @ChristophJohn Many Thanks for response, The actual message is delimited by the SOH character which got removed while pasting message here. I have updated the message with delimiter "^A".

Comment: And tag 9064 is contained in your dictionary at that position (i.e. before the 711 group)?

Comment: @ChristophJohn Yes , 9064 is ExchangeSilo and 711 is NoUnderlyings .Updated the message with that segment of DD

Comment: Maybe the error shows on your last iteration? Why are you iterating until 33 + 1?

Comment: Because using "until" there , but its happening for the first entry also. Updated the code and also provided the  link to DD , if you want to recreate the issue

Comment: Ok last try. ;) Did you try to print out your complete message and does it look the same as before parsing? BTW which language is this? Looks like a mixture of Java and something else.

Comment: Yes I printed the message and it was same. Language is scala , we are parsing the message to store in Big data lake using spark-scala and the printout of the code pasted in question is below  :   Underlyings 3
Exception in thread "main" quickfix.FieldNotFound: 711, index=1
 at quickfix.FieldMap.getGroup(FieldMap.java:644)

Comment: @ChristophJohn Any luck ? :)

Comment: Currently no access to computer, only mobile. What happens when you call `dd.validate` on the message after construction? Any errors?

Comment: Yes there is (Finally got some error :)   :     Exception in thread "main" quickfix.FieldException: Tag not defined for this message type, field=9203
 at quickfix.Message.checkFieldValidation(Message.java:747)
 at quickfix.Message.parseGroup(Message.java:713)

Comment: @ChristophJohn  checked the tag 9203 is present in my data dictionary , not sure why this is saying tag not defined.

Comment: Is it also present in the definition of the 711 repeating group? Or in whatever component it needs to be?

Comment: I am now getting "Out of order repeating group members" . Also found this link : http://quickfix-j.364392.n2.nabble.com/Out-of-order-repeating-group-members-td5416062.html    . So will try reordering my DD as per ICE messages and see how it goes

Comment: Yes, in a repeating group the fields need to be in the same order as in the dictionary.

Comment: It was a long way ;)